# Proportions are broken in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

The easiest way to describe the problem might be with a picture:

[image: Broken proportions in Qt app]

Here is another example:

[image: Broken table headers in Qt app]

There is no special rendering code for that combo box. Other places are suffering from broken proportions as well. Title bars of docking windows are too large. 16x16 icons are blown up to be 32x32. Some toolbars are smaller than the should be.

This happens whenever I build Qt 4 from source. I have tried every combination of flags, settings, compilers, and every version since 4.8.4, and nothing makes any difference. This screenshot is from Qt 4.8.6, not built by me, but by the fine people maintaining the Homebrew project. The official distribution of Qt 4 does not have this problem, but it also doesn't run on 32-bit Macs, so it doesn't work for me.

I'm assuming it's some broken setting on my computer, since nobody else seems to have this problem.

Comment: Why don't you file a bug report to Digia?

Comment: @xylosper: how do you know for _sure_ that it is a bug in Qt itself? Even then, Digia is not the only player. In fact, this module is maintained by KDAB. Anyway, it feels like custom building bug with the homebrew crew or the environment, not upstream Qt.

Comment: So it happens only on mac or not?

Comment: I am not sure this is a bug in Qt itself. Like I said in the last sentence, I think it's something on my machine, because I'm sure the Homebrew people would have found out about it if it happened to everyone.

Comment: @UmNyobe, I haven't tried on Windows. The official distribution of Qt works for my use case on Windows, so I just don't know.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't 32bit version of Qt use Carbon API on Mac OS X? Also could you specify on which version of Mac OS X you are running your app?

Comment: Another thing that I'm not sure about, but on Mac OS X it's against UI guidelines to put icon into combo box. Thats where your proportion problem may come from.

Comment: @KamilKlimek, this is on Mavericks, but I had the same problem before I upgraded. The problem is not limited to the combo box. It was just the most egregious, so I posted the screenshot of that.

Comment: Default Qt Mac OS X theme is trying to keep Mac UI guidelines - when you're trying to vary it (by putting icon to combo box for example) it may not behave correctly. To achieve what you need you have to use CSS and style whole control to behave like you want

Comment: @KamilKlimek, it's not about the combo box. That's just the most egregious example. I will post another screenshot tonight.

Comment: I added one more screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Maybe you should try older oficial version of Qt for Mac http://download.qt-project.org/archive/qt/4.7/ - you should download Carbon version as this should be supporting 32bit apps